# JSON Payload POST request always timing out AWS ApiGateway

Tags: haskell, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, servant

I have gotten POST and GET requests to work when the parameters are entered in the URL. However posting a JSON payload results in my endpoint timing out and the api gateway logs are useless to debug what's going on. This is my API in servant:

```
type ItemApi = "updateitem" :> ReqBody '[JSON] UpdateItem :> Post '[JSON] String

data UpdateItem = UpdateItem {itmId :: String}

instance FromJSON UpdateItem where
  parseJSON = withObject "UpdateItem" $ \v -> do
    id <- v .: "itmId"
    return $ UpdateItem id

updateItemHandler :: UpdateItem -> Handler String
updateItemHandler (UpdateItem _) = do
  liftIO $ updateItem 3 999
  mItem <- liftIO $ checkForExistingItem 3
  liftIO $ print "Updated"
  liftIO $ print $ show mItem
  return "Return Updated"

updateItem :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
updateItem itemId amt = do
 conn <- connect connectIn
 mItem <- checkForExistingItem itemId
 case mItem of
  Just itm ->  do runBeamPostgres conn $ runUpdate $ save (_shoppingItem shoppingCartDb)
                     $ itm { _itemAmount = amt }
                  mItem <- checkForExistingItem itemId
                  print $ show mItem
                  close conn
  Nothing -> do print $ "Item id: " <> show itemId <> " does not exist"
                close conn

checkForExistingItem :: Int -> IO (Maybe Item)
checkForExistingItem id = do
  conn <- liftIO $ connect connectIn
  mTalEntry <-
    runBeamPostgres conn
      $ runSelectReturningOne
      $ select
      $ checkForExistingItemExpression id
  close conn
  return mTalEntry

checkForExistingItemExpression
  :: Int -> Q Postgres ShoppingCartDb s (ItemT (QExpr Postgres s))
checkForExistingItemExpression id =
  filter_ (\item -> _itemId item ==. (val_ id))
    $ all_ (_shoppingItem shoppingCartDb)
```

I'm using Postman to test my request with the following payload:
`{ "itmId": "test" }`

This is my serverless.yml file:

```
service: serverless-minimal-example-final

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: haskell
  region: us-east-1
  timeout: 30

functions:
  apigw:
    handler: serverless-haskell-example.apigw
    events:
      - http:
          path: updateitem
          method: post

plugins:
  - serverless-haskell
  - serverless-offline
```

Comment: What happens when you test with a local instance of your server, running on your own development machine?

Comment: what does `updateItem` do? I think we need to see this function. Could that be some long-running process? (Edit: same with `checkForExistingItem`, now I've read the code more carefully.)

Comment: @BobDalgleish I can use the functions directly to update my Postgres db in amazon RDS. When going through the api gateway is when it times out.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I just updated my question with the code